How to list event types via API including round robin events?
I'm stuck trying to list all my event types (including round robin events) via the Calendly API.
If I ping https://api.calendly.com/event_types/ with my organization in params, I get a list of the user-specific events. However, it's missing all round robin type event types.
It's not a permission issue: I can call the API with a specific round robin event type ID (https://api.calendly.com/event_types/{event_type_id}), and I do get the details for it.
Why isn't that event included in the results of the list call above, and how can I list all the round robin events via Calendly API?
